# parfor Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals

Tags: matlab, indexing, parfor

It is my first time use parfor, and I got this error Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. I can't find what's going wrong?

```
shape = zeros(nFile, 36);
parfor i = 1 : nFile
     if(i <= nFile1)
        imgName = strcat(query_folder1, query_pt1(i).name);
    else
        imgName = strcat(query_folder2, query_pt2(i-nFile1).name);
    end
    tic;
    img = imread(imgName);
    hist = edge_histogram(img, 24);
    fxt = fxt + toc;
    shape(i,:) = hist;
end
```

Comment: It does not look like a parfor-specific error. At what line does the error occur? What is nFile1?

Comment: nFile, nFile1 is number

Comment: where is the error ocurring?

Comment: Any chance nFile is zero?

Comment: at parfor, dbstop if error, display i is a complex number.  nFile could't not be zero..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in line 6, i-nFile1 is below 0.
You should probably change it to (nFile1-i+1), which is between 1 and nFile1.